# How to read Geo Coordinates From Image Property using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an image with longitude and latitude coordinates, can any one tell me how do i get it? I have tried

```
 if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
           {
               MediaFile photoPicked = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
               if (photoPicked != null)
               {
                   //await DisplayAlert("Photo Location", photoPicked.Path, "OK");
                   //path = photoPicked.Path;
                   using (Stream streamPic = photoPicked.GetStream())
                   {
                       var picInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(streamPic);
                       ExifOrientation orientation = picInfo.Orientation;
                       //MainImage123.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => photoPicked.GetStream());
                       latitude = picInfo.GpsLatitude;
                       longitude = picInfo.GpsLongitude;
                       var filepath = photoPicked.AlbumPath;
                       var filepath1 = photoPicked.Path;
                   }
               }
           }
```

It works when I picked photo and trying to get its coordinates, but I have to take multiple photos from image gallery and find its coordinates.
does any one know how to read image geo coordinates? please help me.

Comment: I don't understand.  You say the code you have "works" so what else do you expect us to explain?

Comment: I think he is trying to make it work with multiple images together. How he can be able to pick multiple images together and do whatever he has done in loop.

Comment: but for my case, I can't get the lat/long info,  I just want to get one photo but still can't get it, it always return 0 in a double array, do you have any ideas? thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ExifLib.PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExifLib.PCL/) Nuget Package to read an image metada, by viewing your "code sample", i think you are using the [Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to take images/get images from the galery, be sure to use `SaveMetaData = true` when taking an photo from your app.
Once you have set the **SaveMetaData** to **true**, use the **ExifLib** to obtain the MetaData like this:

```
        MediaFile photo;

        using (Stream streamPic = photo.GetStream())
        {
            var picInfo = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(streamPic);
            double lat = picInfo.GpsLatitude;
            double lon = picInfo.GpsLongitude;
        }
```

Also, as a **plus**, you have even more info on the photo (date taken, author, size, etc.).

**UPDATE:**

After Reading it again, it seems that the problem is that you are not able to pick multiple images from the galery, and **NOT** being able to get the lat and lon from the photos. At the moment, Plugin.Media doesn't support multi-picking.

Comment: I think he is trying to make it work with multiple images together. How he can be able to pick multiple images together and do whatever he has done in loop.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi after reading it close, you are right, i though that he wasn't getting metadata from when he takes pictures (since he said it was working when picking images) because he didn't set SaveMetaData to true, because Plugin.Media doesn't even support multiple pick. i guess i will edit the question so it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was unclear however - I think you are trying to make it work with multiple images together. How you can be able to pick multiple images together?

The plugin "CrossMedia" doesn't support picking up multiple images.

Your solution requires a lot of work to be done to be able to Pickup multiple images at once. So Follow this nice step-by-step tutorial here:

https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/

With above you will be able to get all the images you need at once.
After you get List, all you have to do is to loop through those images and call your existing code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually my question was to take any image from gallery and read its geo coordinates. exiflib.pcl plugin work with no doubts,what I am trying to do is, display all the images in grid which is in gallery and on click of any image want to read its property. And it done successfully :) Sorry it was unclear and thanks again.